# Trouble integrating Django-cms with django-2.0.3

Tags: django, django-cms

I realize there is a subjective element to this question but I have to ask for help from this community.

This is the first time I'm dabbling with django-cms. It uses django-1.11 whereas the current `django --V` is 2.0.3 . I need to use v2 and last night I was trying to make django-cms compatible with django 2.0.3.

Trust me, it's a nightmare. After around 20 fixes, I gave up. The docs aren't very good either - for instance, what should `on_delete` do? - `models.CASCADE`, `models.DO_NOTHING`, etc, etc, - and it differs for many2 many relationships, many2one relationships, etc.

Therefore my question is - is it worth the effort and time to try and make both work together (once again, I have to go with `django-2.0.3` - that is non-negotiable) or just skip it and try to develop a CMS with pure django (& some plugins/libraries, perhaps).

The project will have multiple pages and should have the functionalities to edit both from the front-end side and back-end side. A few tables would receive dynamic data which has to be displayed immediately. There's more to the project but for now, this is the requirement. Am I trying to use a bulldozer to break a paper machete or will cms actually help in the long run in ways that pure django will have difficulty achieving the same results?

Comment: Why do you have to use Django 2? Django 1.11 is the LTS release with support until at least 2020. Equally CMS 3.4 is LTS. I'm curious what the argument against LTS releases could be. Also Django CMS support for Django 2 is coming in 3.6; https://www.django-cms.org/en/roadmap/

Comment: I know al that. But the client's demands are to use the latest version if everything - as in, Python 3.6.4 (if 3.7 were moved from dev to stable, they would have asked for 3.7), Django 2.0.3 and not 1.11.11  - it's not my decision. Hence all the issues. In any case, we've decided to eschew django-cms (so the question above is moot now) and go with some other compatible libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave comments but if your flexible on your CMS, I use Wagtail and it works with Django 2 (Python3). I find it pretty simple to use, but there some things you might find odd.

For example and most noticeably, the MVC of Django is explicitly separated into the models.py, views.py and urls.py. In wagtail, most everything is specified in models.py because wagtail does the heavy lifting of the views.py and urls.py.

Once you get use to this, it's not that bad and the documentation has improved a lot over the past few years.